# Checking the quality of an Incoming Video with python

Tags: python, opencv

I am new to python and programming in general.  I was wondering if there is a way to validate that you are getting a video feed and not just a black screen from an incoming call.  I have automated a script in Python that makes a call and answers the call, but some of the issues we are testing is how often we get black screen instead of the video call.  I have been reading up on OpenCV and played around with it some, but am not getting anywhere near the results I am looking for.  Is there another way in python to detect video?  If so I would greatly appreciate being pointed in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: There might well be better approaches. But in OpenCV you can detect corners (Harris) or edges (Canny).In a blank frame you would not have any features.

Comment: Thanks I will look into those a little farther and see if I can work something out with those.

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar with C++ in OpenCV. There are a couple of ways to go about this.
I use TCP/IP protocols - make sure I don't have packet loss.
Next, To test quality, I send and receive a Video file (that I recorded from the camera) instead of stream "new" video from the camera. Now, I can check the quality by checking the bytes received in every frame.

This may not be optimal, but it is a starting point.